# Why does not all the current flows through Zener diode?

Tags: voltage, current, voltage-regulator, diodes

Let's assume the following circuit, where Zener diode is used as a voltage regulator. R16 (R18 later) is the load.

[image]

When the input voltage is sufficiently high for Zener diode to be reverse-biased, according to the current-voltage curve of the Zener diode, the current will flow through it. Also, I know that the resistance of the diode is very small (milliOhms) when it is opened.

Considering all of the above, I guess we can exchange the diode with the resistor of low resistance (R20 in the image below).

[image]

Now we can calculate the currents through R20

[image]

So, if the load has a small resistance, then most of the current will flow through Zener diode.

My questions are:

- Is it the correct interpretation of Zener diode's functioning?
- Do we use it for the loads, where only the voltage is important?

Comment: Try read this https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/269306/load-resistance-determination-in-zener-diode/269325#269325 and this https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/352448/understanding-zener-diode-datasheet/352458#352458

Answer (score 5):

No, you cannot replace a zener diode with a resistor. You **can** replace the diode with a voltage source, equal to the zener voltage, in series with a small resistor. But this model **only** applies if the zener is reverse biased, meaning that current flows **into** the positive terminal of the voltage source.

In your second paragraph you say "the current will flow through it [the zener]" but it is more accurate to say "**some** current will flow". Some current also flows through R16, because it has a voltage across it (the zener voltage).